# Graphing simple 3d axis

Tags: pgfplots, 3d, tikz-3dplot, pst-solides3d, pst-3dplot

[image]

How to draw 3d axis with component like this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the TeX code you tried so far!

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, following code may be used:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

% Drawing
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{120}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [scale=3,
        tdplot_main_coords,
        axis/.style={->,blue,thick},
        vector/.style={-stealth,red,very thick},
        dot/.style = {circle, fill, minimum size=#1,
              inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
        dot/.default = 6pt,>=latex]

    %standard tikz coordinate definition using x, y, z coords
    \coordinate (E) at (3,0,0);
    \coordinate (D) at (3,0,1);
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0,1);
    \coordinate (B) at (0,3,1);
    \coordinate (G) at (0,3,0);
    \coordinate (F) at (3,3,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (3,3,1);

    %draw axes
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (4,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,4,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
    \draw [thick](E)--(D)--(A)--(B)--(G)--(F)--cycle;
    \draw (D)--(C)--(B);
    \draw (C)--(F);
    
    %draw dots and labels
    \foreach \L in {A,B,C,D,E,F,G}{
    \node[dot,label=left:$\L$] at (\L) {};}
    \node at (C)[right] {$(3,3,1)$};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But how to adjust the x-axis to point towards the observer like this definition. [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-dimensional_space#/media/File:Coord_planes_color.svg) I try to change main coords and set rotated but it doesn't success.